# `Cannot use import statement outside a module` when combining RN and ts-node

Tags: typescript, react-native, ts-node

I created a small CLI tool to automate some process on my React Native project.
Recently I had to update the `RN` from `0.61.4` to `0.63.2` to address some iOS issues.
Since this update, the CLI is not working anymore.

The errors are:

```
yarn ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./scripts/check
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and

```
yarn ts-node -r esm -r tsconfig-paths/register ./scripts/check
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
       ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I've tried a bunch of solutions but feels that I fix A and break B, and vice-versa.
Important to mention that some files from this CLI are shared with the RN app, and the RN app is working fine.

I believe I need to clear the `flow` typings from `RN`, but  `@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` did not help

Comment: AccessibilityInfo is inside of `React Native` code, so, inside of `node_modules`

Comment: `import typeof` isn't valid code, `import type` is, is the goal to import the default type export or are you trying to capture the typeof the module?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I believe "import typeof" os from flow types, you can check the file at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/index.js

Comment: That file doesn't exist in [version 0.61](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/0.61-stable) so clearly architecture changed. `ts-node` definitely doesn't have any capability to deal with flow typing in a js file, RN relies on Babel to deal with that so I'm a little surprised it worked in a previous version...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen any suggestion on how to make this node command work with typescript and stuff? I tried `@babel/node` but also failed for similar reasons...

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? @SidFerreira

Comment: @Rishabh876 no news on this front...

Comment: I faced the similar issue, it was due to wrong cli path in app/build.gradle 
replaced `node_modules/react-native` with `node_modules/react-native/cli.js` and it worked.